# Verificação geral no Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tenho um site em laravel com um painel administrativo. Gostaria de saber como faço para implementar uma verificação geral. Por exemplo:

No meu painel de controle eu tenho uma tela de parâmetros do site, com um checkbox que marca se o site está em manutenção ou não. Caso esteja, o usuário não poderá acessar nenhuma das rotas do site como "/", "/contato", "/reserva". Ele terá que ser redirecionado para a rota "/manutencao". Como posso fazer uma verificação em um único local para não precisar duplicar código?

Comment: É possível implementar um Middleware para isso. Ou então utilizar o modo manutenção do Laravel (https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/configuration#maintenance-mode)